# joining multiple tables, then grouping and suming in linq

Tags: linq

How could I get this SQL query right in LINQ?
SQL query:

```
select c.Name, sum(t.value)
from Categories c
join Items i on c.Id = i.CategoryId
join Transactions t on t.ItemId = i.Id
where datepart(YEAR, t.CreatedTime) = 2016 
        and datepart(MONTH, t.CreatedTime) = 2
group by c.Name
```

I've tried to do the same in LINQ and got this:

```
var query = from cat in _context.Categories
                    join item in _context.Items on cat.Id equals item.CategoryId
                    join trans in _context.Transactions on item.Id equals trans.ItemId
                    where trans.CreatedTime.Month == e.RowIndex && trans.CreatedTime.Year == 2016
                    group new { cat.Name, trans.Value } by cat.Name into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Value = g.Sum(entry => entry.Value)
                    };
```

But it seems to be totally wrong, besides not giving me back the category names, it returns wrong values for the sums as well.

I have three tables: 
Categories with columns Id and Name
Items with columns Id, Name, CategoryId, LastValue, IsIncome,
Transactions with columns Id, ItemId, Value, CreatedTime, IsIncome

Comment: You can use `g.Key` to get the category name.  Other than that, everything seems ok and should give you the same result as your SQL query. What do you see if you say `var sql = query.ToString();`?

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, that was all, g.Key solves the problem and on a second try it returns the correct answers, I just got confused. :)